# Devise_invitable : wrong flash upon successfull invitation edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Gemfile :

```
gem 'devise',           '>= 2.0.0'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.3.4'
```

Users accessing `/invitation/accept.XX?invitation_token=XXXXXXXX` successfully set their password using this form:

```
<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :invitation_token %>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.edit.submit_button"), class:'btn btn-inverse' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Upon succes, they get signed_in and redirected to the intended page, however they get the flash message located in :

> ```
> en:  
>  devise:  
>   invitations:  
>    invitation_token_invalid: 'The invitation token provided is not valid!'
> ```

Any idea why so?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, not sure if the cause of your issue. I had modified the devise redirect after sign in, which caused my application to try to accept the invitation a second time. This causes the error: 'The invitation token provided is not valid!' since DeviseInvitable deletes the invitation_token after the user successful accepts the invitiation the first time.

My problem code was:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scoped)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

@Steve is correct, as that line is what was causing this error for me as well. In particular, its the `session[:previous_url]`.

Here is my workaround that fixes the issue for me.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
```

**Users::InvitationsController**

```
module Users
  class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
    def after_accept_path_for(resource)
      root_path # you can define this yourself. Just don't use session[:previous_url]
    end
  end
end
```

Essentially here the default behavior is to use `after_sign_in_path_for` as the path after a resource accepts an invitation. The above solution just overrides that default behavior. You can check the [docs](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#integration-in-a-rails-application) for more information.

Comment: This was my problem exactly! I've been combing the internet all day. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR BEING YOU. Also, this would be a helpful thing to include in the gem docs for devise_invitable, yes?

Comment: Glad you were able to get your problem solved. I believe this is already in the docs in the [third paragraph under "Integration in a Rails application"](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#integration-in-a-rails-application).

Comment: Now that I know what it is, I agree. Putting the specific error in there would make it easier to understand.